# How do I obtain and use the current directory of the exe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, arrays

This code works:

```
Public Sub Install()
    progDirectory = )
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", My.Resources.Resource, False)
    Unzip(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", SelFolder)
End Sub
```

But this does not:

```
Dim progDirectory As 

Public Sub Install()
    progDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", progDirectory, False)
    Unzip(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", SelFolder)
End Sub
```

The basic gist of what I am trying to accomplish, is to find the current directory/path of the exe, and then locate a 'Resource.zip' file from that directory.

The top section of code writes the .zip file to the selection location (SelFolder) unzips it, and then deletes the Resource.zip from that folder.

The second section of code is intended to do the same thing, but use a zip from a directory rather than the app resources as I want them to be separate.

The error I get is: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'. On this line:

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", progDirectory, False)

Comment: For the error is simply because the second argument for WriteAllByes should be a byte array while you pass a string. For the rest, your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Use: `File.Copy(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", progDirectory)`

Instead of: `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(SelFolder & "\Resource.zip", progDirectory, False)`

Answer (score 0):

The current path of the executable can be obtained through the property [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx).

There are other ways to get it as well, but we found years ago when writing code that was executed on multiple platforms, including Windows Mobile, that this was the safest way to retrieve the information.

So, you can change your progDirectory assignment to:

```
    progDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```